# Is it possible to create a C ++ program, just linking to libcstdc ++, without linking to libc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm starting to study c ++, and I got a doubt, when I use the ldd program and see the dependencies of the dynamic libraries, notice that besides the c++ standard library which is libstdc ++, libc is also compiled, and it is possible to make a program executable without libc, only with libstdc ++?

How to compile this code withou?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "AAA";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on your implementation.  Most implementations of libstdc++ depend on libc, so they require it.

Comment: You can statically link libc and libstdc++

Comment: The C++ standard includes most of the C standard library. So it's kind of a dependency and technically it's part of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of the C standard library functions are actually also part of the C++ standard library ("STL" for short.) The `<cstdlib>` header for example, which provides functions like `std::malloc()` and `std::system()`, is part of the STL.

Note that even if you didn't ever use one of those functions explicitly, the STL will still make use of them as an implementation detail. `std::copy()` for example might call `std::memcpy()`. Comparing two `std::string` objects might result in a call to `std::memcmp()`.

The compiler itself will do so too in many cases. `new` for example might result in a call to `std::malloc()`, and `delete` might call `std::free()`. Or if a `noexcept` function throws, the C++ standard says that `std::terminate()` will be called, which in turn is defined as calling `std::abort()` by default, which is a C library function from `<cstdlib>`.

Most C++ compiler and library implementations will simply re-use the C library rather than re-implement it. In other words, libc can be considered part of libstdc++ from the perspective of a C++ program. It just happens to be split into a separate library file. So if you link against libstdc++, you also need to link against libc.

Comment: I think [referring to the C++ standard library as the "STL" might not be entirely correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5205491/9254539).

Comment: @AlexanderZhang It's been retrofitted by convention to mean "**St**andard **L**ibrary, because most people just call it STL. Writing "C++ standard library" every single time is just tiring. When people say "STL" these days, they don't refer to Stepanov's library.

Answer (score 3):

On most UNIX platforms, libc contains the implementations of basic system call wrappers, like `read()`, `write()`, and `_exit()`. These functions are used by all applications, including ones which are written in C++. Indeed, the implementations of many C++ standard library functions will make use of these wrappers -- for example, using the `<<` operator on `std::cout` will call the libc implementation of `write()`.

So: probably not. If you're on any kind of UNIX system, libstdc++ will depend on libc, so you'll need to link against libc. (Windows is a rather different situation, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're using.)

Comment: The C++ standard includes most of the C standard library. So it's kind of a dependency and technically it's part of the C++ standard library.